# How to summarise with sum dependent on another column - using dplyr

Tags: r

I am looking to perform a group by on id, code1 and then summarise. I want the summarise to do several conditional sums i.e. sum of the count column when code2 == "B". I know how to do this by creating an intermediary binary column but I was wondering if there is quicker method where this can all be performed in the summarise statement.

Here is some test data:

```
id <- c(1,1,1)
code1 <- c("M", "M", "M")
code2 <- c("B", "B", "U")
code3 <- c("H", "N", "N")
count <- c(15, 2, 1)
x <- data.frame(id, code1, code2, code3, count)
```

Desired output:

```
id | code1 | Total | B_count | U_count | H_count | N_count
1    M       18      17        1         15        3
```

Comment: you can use the group by and mutate function in dplyr

Answer (score 3):

We can use the conditions inside the `summarise` call:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  group_by(id, code1) %>% 
  summarise(total = sum(count),
            B_count = sum(count[code2 == "B"]),
            U_count = sum(count[code2 == "U"]),
            H_count = sum(count[code3 == "H"]),
            N_count = sum(count[code3 == "N"]))

`summarise()` regrouping output by 'id' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 1 x 7
# Groups:   id [1]
     id code1 total B_count U_count H_count N_count
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1 M        18      17       1      15       3
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is very complicated but it gets the job done.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = matches('code[2-9]'),
    names_to = 'vars',
    values_to = 'code'
  ) %>%
  dplyr::select(-vars) %>%
  group_by(id, code1, code) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(count), .groups = "rowwise") %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(id, code1),
    names_from = code,
    values_from = count
  ) %>%
  left_join(
    x %>%
    group_by(id, code1) %>%
    summarise(Total = sum(count), .groups = "rowwise"), 
    by = c("id", "code1")
  ) %>%
  select(id, code1, Total, everything())
## A tibble: 1 x 7
#     id code1 Total     B     H     N     U
#  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 M        18    17    15     3     1
```